import.meta.env. get error Unexpected "export" in astro
I am facing a problem with using the environment variable in an Astro project.
My .env file has PUBLIC_DOMAIN = 'https://abc.com.vn/'.
The structure of my project is:

The problem is, when I type const DOMAIN = import.meta.env.PUBLIC_DOMAIN in any .astro file in the components, it works fine and I can get PUBLIC_DOMAIN. But if a file uses that line in any file in pages/[lang], it causes an error like Unexpected "export".
The error caused by the code looks like:
import {getLangFromUrl, useTranslations} from '../../i18n/utils'
import {languages} from '../../i18n/ui'
const DOMAIN = import.meta.env.PUBLIC_DOMAIN

const lang = getLangFromUrl(Astro.url)
const t = useTranslations(lang)

export async function getStaticPaths() {
    return languages.map((lang) => {
        return {params: {lang}}
    })
}

I want to ask why this is happening, and how I can solve it. Thanks so much for any support.

Does adding a semicolon help? (btw. astro is using vite for this under the hood). Otherwise, can you create an example via https://astro.new ?

I have finally found out that I have to delete the ‘.git’ line from the .gitignore file :))
